# cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

OK, it drives me crazy! I try to run ruby / rails.

```
    MacBook-Pro-2:Library me$ rvm list
    rvm rubies
       ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
    # => - current
    # =* - current && default
    #  * - default
    MacBook-Pro-2:Library me$ rvm use 2.1.0
    Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
    <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb    (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

   MacBook-Pro-2:Library me$gem list
   <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
   from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I provide any information to solve that problem. 
What is wrong? I can't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would recommend uninstalling ruby-2.1.0 and then reinstalling it as it seems like your current installation is corrupted.

```
rvm uninstall 2.1.0
rvm install 2.1.0
```

Comment: Though this solved the issue, it would be nice to know what is actually wrong. I suspect it has something to do with the PATH variable.