# irb cannot run in terminal: <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, irb

Everything was working fine last night but today after I tried to install Rails irb is no longer able to run

```
shaunyap:~ shaun.yap$ irb
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
shaunyap:~ shaun.yap$
```

I've reinstalled rvm and Ruby

rvm 1.25.22 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

Will appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310297/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the solution flagged worked for OP but not for me.