# rubygems.rb (LoadError) in local project RoR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I need to use Rails 2.1.1 and Ruby 3.2.13 on current project.

Can't start a rails server locally. I use RVM for managing rails versions.

Here is a log I have in a terminal inside of project folder:

```
$ rvm use 2.1.1
Using .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load 
such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
$ which ruby
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
$ rails server
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

What the problem? Where I need to look at? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310297/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb — this seem to be related somehow.

Answer (score 2):

the most common cause of:

```
$ rails server
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
```

is that the `rails` command (/gem) is used from wrong ruby version, to fix it run:

```
rvm use . --install          # switch to proper ruby
rvm rubygems latest --force  # make sure rubygems is installed in this ruby
gem install bundler          # make sure bundler is installed
bundle install               # make sure all gems for your project are installed
```

Comment: Thanks @mpapis! It will be good hint for me for the future. This time solved it with reinstalling rvm, ruby, rails and bundle.